# How to deal with entity relations when fetching data via REST API?

Tags: java, rest, spring-rest

Suppose you have an entity `User` within a typical Java web application. E.g. Spring framework, Hibernate ORM, and etc. `User` has some relations e.g.:

```
public class User {
    // primitive fields
    private Team team;
    private Set<Group>;
    // ...
}
```

You can easily browse user's graph, e.g. `user.getTeam().getName()`

**What are the best practices of exposing such entities via REST API, and accessing them from Java client?**

E.g. when I need to load a user by `id`. Should I get a response that also contains `team`, and `groups`? What if I don't need those relations each time user is fetched.

*The question is more about designing a Java client.*

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it depends on the, in your case, the `Team` object's size and usage. If it is very small or it's always needed when you need a user, you may attach it directly to the `User` when calling `Get /users/{id}`. Otherwise it would get the `Team` with `Get /users/{id}/team`.

Best practice would be [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS). A call to `Get /users/{id}` would return you a user json object, which also indicates the team property by including the path (`Get /users/{id}/team`) to it. But as this is a lot of work, one might to not go that extra step.

Comment: Thanks, Herr! Yes, HATEOAS is a way of working, and pretty good, I used it. But still, it is not clear to me how to build a Java client. Suppose you make a call to the REST API and get a response with links. What kind of Data Transfer Object will you use to handle such responses in Java?

Comment: Ìf you want to go with HATEOS, which would be laudable ;), Spring has the `spring-hateoas` framework, which will do a lot for you. Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.23.0.RELEASE/reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/learn/). This API Query Language permits a client to query only specific fields from your entities.

For example, in your case, the client would make the following query to load also the team:

```
{
  user {
    team
  }
}
```

If the client needs only the user name then this could be the query:

```
{
  user {
    name
  }
}
```

You can find a Java implementation [here](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java).